# is there a way to make a method behave differently based on the object that calls it in java?

Tags: java, methods

I have a game were making for a project and in it are different types of buildings with different stats such as Level and Cost (ex: Farms and Markets - theyre all subclasses of the main class Buildings) and there is an upgrade() method i want to implement that will upgrade some preexisting values differently for each building depending on which one its called on. i have these set of values in a table.

ex:
if i want to upgrade a Farm, then the player will write Farm.upgrade() and this will change the farm's level to 2 and upgrade the cost to a certain value (lets say 700)

but if i want to upgrade a Market then the same .upgrade() will be called and this will change the market's level to 2 and the cost to 1000 for example

i have about 5 buildings each with their own set of values that come with the update() action, i feel like the solution has something to do with the parent class but i cant crack it. or maybe i have to make multiple versions of the method? but i doubt thats what im required to do here

Answer (score 0):

You can create abstract method in class `Building` and now every class that extends this `Building` class will need to implement this method. It will look something like this :

```
abstract class Building {

  int cost, level;

  abstract void upgrade();
}

class Farm extends Building {

  @Override
  void upgrade() {
    // upgrade level and set cost to X
  }
}

class Market extends Building {

  @Override
  void upgrade() {
      // upgrade level and set cost to X
  }
}
```

Now you can call `upgrade()` on Farm and it will behave differently than invoking same method on Market instance.

Answer (score 0):

- First approach (Which I recommend)

Assume the parent class `Building`. It should declare an `upgrade` method and allow the child classes to have it's own implementation.

```java
public class Building {

    public void upgrade() {
        // you could provide a default implementation.
        // or throw a run time Exception to enforce implementation in child.
    }

}

public class Market extends Building{
    @Override
    public void upgrade() {
        this.value += 200; // any required logic.
    }
}
```

Other child classes also extend and override the upgrade method.

- Second approach (use generics)

```java
public <T extends Building> void upgrade(T object) {
    if(object instanceof Market) {
        // there is a better single step way to do the type check and object creation in Java 16.
        Market m = (Market) object;
        //logic
    }
    // similar operation for other child classes.

}
```